# How can I sum each list within a nested list using a Python function?

Tags: python, function

I have a random set of test scores for 50 students.  Each student answered 20 questions, and the maximum score for each question is 5. How can I get the total score of each student in a list by using a Python function?

```
results_sheet = []
num_of_questions = 20
num_students = 50


#generate scores for each student and append to results_sheet

for student in range(num_students):
        scores = random.choices(list(range(0,6)),k=num_of_questions)
        results_sheet.append(scores)
        
#The result here is a list of lists.
```

So if I call the results for 2 students, I will get the following:

```
print(results_sheet[0:2])
[[4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 3], [5, 1, 1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 5, 3, 1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4]]
```

I have tried the following code but am missing something. Or perhaps the code is simply wrong:

```
def sum_score(results_sheet):

total = 0
for val in results_sheet:
    total = total + val
return total
```

The end result should look something like this for 2 students:

```
total_scores = [47, 55]
```

Comment: Are you resetting the results_sheet between each loop iteration?

Comment: What that piece of code you provided returns. Because i'm not sure how the result_sheet looks like. Is it 2D list looking like `result_sheet[num_students][num_of_questions]`

Comment: Pythonically `[*total_scores] = map(sum, results_sheet)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a list comprehension:

```
final = [sum(lst) for lst in results_sheet]
```

Or use `map`:

```
final = list(map(sum, results_sheet))
```

**Edit:**

To use a function:

```
def func(results_sheet):
    return [sum(lst) for lst in results_sheet]
print(func(results_sheet))
```

Comment: Thank you, @U11-Forward. Both solutions were helpful. What if I wanted to use a function to solve the problem?

Comment: @CTan Check my **Edit:** part, please accept and upvote if it helps

Comment: @CTan I did the function in the recent edit

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use numpy.sum, and set axis to negative.

```
import random
import numpy

results_sheet = []
num_of_questions = 20
num_students = 50


#generate scores for each student and append to results_sheet

for student in range(num_students):
        scores = random.choices(list(range(0,6)),k=num_of_questions)
        results_sheet.append(scores)
```

If you want the sum of all:

```
numpy.sum(results_sheet, axis=-1)

array([43, 44, 61, 64, 52, 44, 48, 51, 36, 50, 51, 45, 56, 47, 53, 60, 53,
       45, 45, 46, 53, 54, 39, 42, 54, 67, 44, 48, 51, 58, 53, 54, 40, 52,
       62, 54, 61, 58, 47, 38, 51, 45, 50, 49, 61, 30, 50, 59, 54, 34])
```

So if I call the results for 2 students:

```
numpy.sum(results_sheet, axis=-1)[0:2]
array([43, 44])
```

Comment: You are welcome. you can also use the following setting,
numpy.sum(results_sheet[A:B], axis=0)[X:Y]
to know the result of students between A and B on the X:Y questions.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you are having a `return` statement outside of a function it will not work. Secondly, you can also just use the build-in `sum` function in Python:

```
sum_of_all = sum(scores)
```

Then you can do this for each individual student's scores:

```
results_sheet = []
num_of_questions = 20
num_students = 50


#generate scores for each student and append to results_sheet

for student in range(num_students):
        scores = random.choices(list(range(0,6)),k=num_of_questions)
        results_sheet.append(scores)

sums = [sum(result_sheet) for result_sheet in results_sheet]
```

The `sums` variable will be a list of summed scores for the students, in the same order as the generated scores.

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply sum() on every 2nd level list, like below

```
import random

results_sheet = []
num_of_questions = 20
num_students = 50


#generate scores for each student and append to results_sheet

for student in range(num_students):
        scores = random.choices(list(range(0,6)),k=num_of_questions)
        results_sheet.append(scores)


total = 0
for val in results_sheet:
    total = total + sum(val)
print(total)
```

Comment: Actually you don't need the second for loop, you can do the sum in the first loop `total = total + sum(scores)`, the code will be faster. Of course you have to set `total = 0` before the 1st loop.

Comment: Thank you, that helps in getting the total score for all students.